# How do I move the Rigidbody in FixedUpdate, but still have my character be affected by gravity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

So

Below you see what I initially used to control my characters movement.

```
_RigidBody.velocity = _ConstantWalkingSpeed * direction.normalized;
```

This works for walking around in 4 directions. However, if my character falls over an edge, he falls veeeeeery slowly. If I then in mid air disable the walking script, gravity picks up and goes at normal speed.

This leads me to believe that my movement script somehow affects the gravity effect.

As such I tried this solution:

```
_RigidBody.velocity = _ConstantWalkingSpeed * direction.normalized + new Vector3(0f, _RigidBody.velocity.y, 0f);
```

That didn't work either, so I tried this:

```
_RigidBody.velocity = _ConstantWalkingSpeed * direction.normalized + new Vector3(0f, _RigidBody.velocity.y, 0f) + Physics.gravity;
```

That did make the gravity work, but then the gravity became so strong that I can't move.

I tried only adding Physics.gravity and skipping the new vector part, but then the gravity is still too strong.

TL;DR

The movement script I use affects the players downward gravity, which it shouldn't. I want him to move around but still be affected by gravity. Ideas I have tried didn't work.

Please note that I'd prefer to keep the gravity at -9.81.

Hoping you guys have a suggestion that works :-)

Comment: I discovered that I was setting the velocity to Vector3.Zero when not receiving input, for a responsive movement feel where the player stops when not ordered to move.

If I remove that, he falls as he should with gravity.

However, as I'd like to retain the responsive feel I'm still looking for a way to both have the responsive stop and the gravity.

Comment: Found a solution where I do a ground check using a raycast. If grounded and no input I set Vector.Zero for responsiveness. If not grounded i disable walking and let gravity take over.

The ultimate solution would be that I could "walk" in air while being affected by gravity, but haven't found a way to do that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting or modifying the velocity, You can use `RigidBody.movePositon`:

Here is a quick example script I wrote up:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class simpleMoveRB : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody myBody;
    public float _constantWalkSpeed = 3.0f;

    Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            moveDirection.x = -1.0f;
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            moveDirection.x = 1.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            moveDirection.x = 0.0f;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            myBody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 500.0f);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
            myBody.MovePosition(transform.position + moveDirection * _constantWalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

You can handle movement using this script, and still have gravity work on your object.

Comment: It can move him with gravity still working. It moves a tad clunky but you did actually provide a solution, so I assigned you as having answered my question.

Comment: @Doh09 there are some parameters you can change on the rigidbody that will affect how this function moves the rigidbody, checkout https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the velocity, modify the velocity.

You're overwriting any velocity applied by the physics engine (e.g. gravity) with your input.

```
_RigidBody.velocity += _ConstantWalkingSpeed * direction.normalized;
```

You may also want to cap the velocity X and Z values to a maximum:

```
Vector3 vel = _RigidBody.velocity;
vel.x = Mathf.Min(vel.x, ConstantWalkingSpeed);
vel.z = Mathf.Min(vel.z, ConstantWalkingSpeed);
_RigidBody.velocity = vel;
```

Comment: How would I go about making this in the responsive way I mentioned in the comments of the above post?

I realized that the gravity stop happened due to applying Vector3.Zero when not making any directional input. I used Vector3.Zero for responsiveness in stopping/starting.

Comment: I don't know where your `direction` value is coming from. If that is your direct input vector, then it will already be 0 when no keys are pressed.