# Cube is falling through terrain - Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, collider

I have a Terrain and Cube. Terrain has terrain collider attached and cube has  box collider on it. But still cube is falling through the terrain. I tried lot of things explained in other questions and on other forums but none of them has fixed the issue. Screenshot of both cube and terrain setting is attached below.

Cube Settings:
[image: Cube Settings]

Terrain Settings:
[image: Terrain Settings]

Comment: Are you using Transform.Translate to move the cube?  If so thats why.

Comment: @Eddge I am not using Transform.Translate to move the cube. I am using transform.position for movement

Comment: let me guess that is happening in update.

Comment: exactly, updating the position to move the cube

Comment: if you want Unity's collision system to work correctly you need to handle all of your movement through their physic system,  by moving the position directly you are bypassing unitys physics updates.

Comment: This might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391634/how-do-i-move-the-rigidbody-in-fixedupdate-but-still-have-my-character-be-affec/48393199#48393199

Comment: so issue is with the move script...

Comment: @Eddge thanks for all the help. Actually I fixed it by adding Character controller on the cube and moving the cube using that character controller.

Comment: np, i bet if you deactivated your scripts, and made the cube use gravity(By adding a rigidbody) it would land on the terrain =)

Comment: yes, I did that, and then changed the movement script. btw thanks for pointing out that problem is in the movement script. But I don't under why we cannot use position to move the cube

Comment: There are 2 reasons for your issue, 1 in order for collisions to happen in unity one of your objects need a rigidbody.  2.  Moving an object by its transform directly in update will bypass the Fixed loop Unity uses for collisions.  So for example you move your object every frame based off of time.deltaTime, when the physics loop happens it will attempt to do a seperation of the 2 objects.  that seperation can only be seperated so much in the physics loops to keep things looking natural,  if you had a slower move rate, and a rigibody on your cube you would probably see it jitter as it passed.

Comment: I totally understand now. Thank you so much...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to add a rigid body to the cude AND make sure that this rigid body has the property of "is Trigger" not enabled, if u needed enabled u need to wrap the whole cube inside empty object and make it enabled in the new wrapper and disabled in the cube, this will solve the probelm

Answer (score 1):

It's because your cube need a rigidBody component.

After manage the gravity with this component and if you have to move your cube do it in the FixedUpdate, not the Update.